# Inequality between a combination and exponential expression

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I am trying to derive an inequality from a paper (maybe it is a standard inequality?). The inequality is stated (without proof) as

$$ \binom{t}{c} < \left(\frac{et}{c}\right)^c$$

Additional information provided: $c \in [0.4t, t]$ and $t\geq 1$.

Here is my initial attempt - I am using sterling's approximation with strictly lower than form from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

$$n! < n^{n+0.5} e^{-n+1}$$ (To get strictly less than)

We know that $\binom{t}{c} = \frac{t!}{c!(t-c)!}$

So substituting sterling's inequality into the binomial equality we get,

$$\binom{t}{c} < \frac{t^{t+0.5} e^{-t+1}}{c^{c+0.5} e^{-c+1} (t-c)^{t-c+0.5} e^{-(t-c)+1}}$$

$$\implies  \binom{t}{c} < e^{-1} \frac{t^{t+0.5}}{c^{c+0.5} (t-c)^{t-c+0.5}}$$

As we know that $t\geq c$, my idea is to replace $t-c$ with $t$ as $c \in [0.4t,t]$. Which would result in the final expression I need on the right (with some constants in exponential). Now my issue is, as I am replacing the RHS expression denominator with larger value, the total value of RHS will decrease so my replacement is not valid to support the inequality. Please help me proceed from here. I apologize in advance if there are any mistakes in my calculations.